# Keycloak, Nodejs API and Traefik all in Docker -> only 403

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, keycloak, traefik

maybe someone can help me.
I have keycloak, my nodejs-server, and traefik all installed with docker-compose. Everything seemed to be fine until I called a route from my frontend to the nodejs API. No matter what I tried I get a 403 all the time. When the nodejs server is running not in a docker it works. Strange in my opinion.
Here my Docker Compose if it helps:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    networks: 
      - keycloak-network
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=
      - MYSQL_USER=
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
    command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1
    volumes:
      - ./:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`keycloak.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true"
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    environment:
      - DB_DATABASE=
      - DB_USER=
      - DB_PASSWORD=
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/example-realm.json
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    volumes:
      - ./realm-export.json:/tmp/example-realm.json
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.rule=Host(`phpmyadmin.localhost`)"
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    links:
      - mariadb:db
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  spectory-backend:
    image: spectory-backend
    container_name: spectory-backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.spectory-backend.rule=Host(`api.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.port=4000"
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - keycloak
  spectory-frontend:
    image: spectory-frontend
    container_name: spectory-frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.spectory-frontend.rule=Host(`spectory.localhost`)"
    ports:
      - 4200:80
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - keycloak
      - spectory-backend
  traefik-reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    command: 
      - --api.insecure=true 
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.file.directory=/configuration/
      - --providers.file.watch=true
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-reverse-proxy.rule=Host(`traefik.localhost`)"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8082:8080"
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.toml:/configuration/traefik.toml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./ssl/tls.key:/etc/https/tls.key
      - ./ssl/tls.crt:/etc/https/tls.crt

networks:
  keycloak-network:
    name: keycloak-network
```

I also tried static ip addresses for nodejs and keycloak -> didn't work.
Here on StackOverflow someone mentioned using https would help -> didn't work
Pretty much my situation: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831754/keycloak-with-node-js-api-fails-through-docker) . The goal for me is that even the API is reachable through traefik

Btw my angular frontend can communicate with keycloak. Also in a docker. I can also ping the keycloak docker from the nodejs docker. Nodejs configuration parameters directly form keycloak.

I really don't know what to do next.
Did someone tried something similar?

Comment: So I think I now got what the problem is:
Because of all the communication is redirected by Traefik the Kauth Header is empty. Therefore the keycloak-connect package cannot check the roles. When the nodejs-server is in the host network and not behind a reverse proxy the Kauth header is still accessible.

Comment: You probably need to add `passHostHeader` and maybe `customrequestheaders` for your Docker provider `label`s

Answer (score 0):

I had possibly the same issue.

To resolve it, I had to make sure that frontend and backend use the same keycloak adress, in my case I now explicitly use  `http://HOST_IP:HOST_KEYCLOAK_PORT` in keycloak config of frontend and backend.

It came from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65952433/1548534