# 403 Forbidden, communication among docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I have an application composed of react-client (frontend), express server (backend), and keycloak. For development purpose, I run keycloak inside a docker-container and expose its corresponding port (8080); frontend and backend run locally on my machine. They connect to keycloak on the aforementioned port. Backend serves some REST end-points and these end-points are protected by keycloak. Everything works fine.

However, when I tried to containerize my application for production purpose by putting backend in a container and run everything with docker-compose (frontend still run on my local machine), backend rejected all requests from frontend, although these requests are attached with a valid token. I guess the problem is that backend cannot connect with keycloak to verify the token but I don't know why and how to fix the problem.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  
  backend:
    image: "backend"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./backend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"

  keycloak:
    image: "jboss/keycloak"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/realm-export.json
    volumes:
      - ./realm-export.json:/tmp/realm-export.json

  mongo_db:
    image: "mongo:4.2-bionic"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  mongo_db_web_interface:
    image: "mongo-express"
    ports:
      - "4000:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo_db
```

This is keycloak configuration in backend code:

```
{
  "realm": "License-game",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "backend",
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

This is keycloak configuration in frontend code:

```
{
    URL: "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
    realm: 'License-game',
    clientId: 'react'
}
```

[This is the configuration of keycloak for backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkFlq.png)

Answer (score 2):

Backend and frontend are using different Keycloak URLs in your case - `http://keycloak:8080/auth/` vs `http://localhost:8080/auth/`, so they are expecting different issuer in the token.

So yes, token from the frontend is valid, but not for the backend. Because that one is expecting different issuer value in the token. Use the same keycloak domain everywhere and you want have this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem this days. As previously answered the problem is within the token issuer.

In order to make it work refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339948/docker-symfony-reactjs-keycloak-how-to-make-an-http-request-from-a-container-t)